# module data is not showing on the frontend

Tags: module, frontend, modal

I am trying to get the my custom module on front end from database but it not showing any thing but just the blank module page:

My controller:

```
  <?php
  class OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    public function IndexAction() {

    $this->loadLayout();   
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__("Reviews"));
    $breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock("breadcrumbs");

        $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("home", array(
        "label" => $this->__("Home Page"),
        "title" => $this->__("Home Page"),
        "link"  => Mage::getBaseUrl()
   ));

      $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("titlename", array(
        "label" => $this->__("Reviews"),
        "title" => $this->__("Reviews")
   ));

    $this->renderLayout(); 


  }
}
```

Here is my block :

```
 <?php
class OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Block_Index extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
    {
     public function index()
    {
        $productId = 1;//change to your product id
        $collection = Mage::getModel('optfirst_reviewmycompany/new_optfirst_reviewmycompany')->getCollection()
         ->addFieldToFilter('id_optfirst_reviewmycompany', $productId);
           return $collection;

   }

}
```

And this is my module template:

```
  <?php
$collection = $this->index();
print_r($collection);
foreach ($collection as $instance) {
          echo  $instance['facebook'].'<br>';
          /* you can customize code here */
          }

     ?>
```

layout Node review.xml

```
  <? xml version = "1.0" ?>   
  <layout version="0.1.0">   
     <reviews_index_index>   
       <reference name="root">   
         <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>   
       </reference>   
       <reference name="content">   
           <block type="reviews/index" name="reviews_index" template="reviews/index.phtml"/>   
      </reference>   
 </reviews_index_index>   
  </layout>
```

here is the front-end template:

[image]

Anyone can look and let me know what is the issue:

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**config.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
    <routers>
      <reviewmycompany>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany</module>
            <frontName>reviewmycompany</frontName>
          </args>
      </reviewmycompany>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <reviewmycompany>
              <file>reviews.xml</file>
            </reviewmycompany>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <reviewmycompany>
                <class>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Block</class>
            </reviewmycompany>
        </blocks>

        <helpers>
            <optfirst_reviewmycompany>
                <class>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Helper</class>
            </optfirst_reviewmycompany>
        </helpers>

        <models>         
            <optfirst_reviewmycompany>
                <class>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>optfirst_reviewmycompany_resource</resourceModel>
            </optfirst_reviewmycompany>
            <optfirst_reviewmycompany_resource>
                <class>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <review>
                        <table>optfirst_reviewmycompany</table>
                    </review>
                </entities>
            </optfirst_reviewmycompany_resource>
        </models>

        <resource>
            <optfirst_reviewmycompany_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </optfirst_reviewmycompany_setup>
            <optfirst_reviewmycompany_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </optfirst_reviewmycompany_write>
            <optfirst_reviewmycompany_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </optfirst_reviewmycompany_read>
        </resource>
    </global>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <optfirst_reviewmycompany after="Mage_Adminhtml">OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Adminhtml</optfirst_reviewmycompany>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <optfirst_reviewmycompany>
                    <file>optfirst_reviewmycompany.xml</file>
                </optfirst_reviewmycompany>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <optfirst_reviewmycompany>
                    <files>
                        <default>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </optfirst_reviewmycompany>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml>

    <default>
        <optfirst_reviewmycompany>
            <general>
                <default_sort_by><![CDATA[position]]></default_sort_by>
            </general>
        </optfirst_reviewmycompany>
    </default>
</config>
```

**reviews.xml**

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">   
  <reviewmycompany_index_index> 
    <reference name="root">   
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>   
    </reference>   
    <reference name="content">   
      <block type="reviewmycompany/index" name="reviewmycompany_index" template="reviews/index.phtml"/>   
    </reference>   
  </reviewmycompany_index_index> 
</layout>
```

Comment: no luck : is there any issue with my template that i am using:
rwd/default

Comment: Ok just add <?php echo "Test";?> in your phtml then reload front end it display or not

Comment: not displaying anything..

Comment: then file is a problem you are adding phtml in theme only right

Comment: update ur xml file

Comment: ok question is updated please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49239/discussion-between-xabby-and-kothari).